# Check Ip Against Server Issue C#

Tags: c#, ip, blacklist

So i have some code that will check if a user is on a ip blacklist list and this is the code i have come up with

```
string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
bool checkipagainstserver = !new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ringarang.github.io/ipchecker.html").Contains(externalip);
```

then it is

`if (checkagainstserver)`

it shows a message box and quits the application

This code builds fine and works. If I change the url, it will catch out but when I add my ip to that list, it doesn't block execution and show message box even though my ip is clearly on that server text file

(the server files are there for testing and will be moved to the domain when done)

Comment: Does `externalip` end up being what you expect it to be when you examine it in the debugger? I'd split out downloading the blacklist and checking if it contains the IP into 2 different statements so the debugger can be useful.

Comment: where would i find the debugger???

Comment: @DaddyJeffKaplan Visual Studio has some magic keys like F9,F5,F10,F11 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it the code needed too be

```
 string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
 WebClient tempWebClient = new WebClient();
 bool checkipagainstserver =
```

then i needed to convert it